# jQuery UI slider isn't updating properly in BMI calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a BMI calculator that calculates the BMI automatically whenever anyone changes a value (without having to click a calculate button). I currently have two select inputs for the feet and inches and then I used jQuery UI to use a slider for the weight input. My problem is that while the select inputs cause the BMI to recalculate, any changes to the slider don't seem to make the BMI recalculate. I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery and appreciate the help.

Javascript:

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sliderWeight").slider({
  value: 150,
  min: 91,
  max: 443,
  slide: function(evt, elem) {
    $("#weight").text(elem.value);
    },
  start: function(evt, elem) {
    $("#weight").addClass("heavytext")
    },
  stop: function(evt, elem) {
    $("#weight").removeClass("heavytext")
   }
 });

$("#weight").text($("#sliderWeight").slider("value"));


function displayVals() {
var feetValues = parseInt($("#feet").val());
var inchValues = parseInt($("#inches").val());
var inches = feetValues * 12 + inchValues;
var weightSlider = parseInt($("#sliderWeight").slider("value"));
var bmiWeight = weightSlider * 703
var bmiHeight = inches * inches
var bmi = Math.round(bmiWeight / bmiHeight);
$("#totalinches").html("You selected: <b>Feet:</b> " + feetValues +
  " <b>Inches:</b> " + inchValues + "<br>That is " + inches + " inches.");
$("#bmi").html("Your BMI is " + bmi);
}
$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="feet">
  <option value="4">4 feet</option>
  <option value="5">5 feet</option>
  <option value="6">6 feet</option>
  <option value="7">7 feet</option>
</select>
<select id="inches">
  <option value="0">0 inches</option>
  <option value="1">1 inches</option>
  <option value="2">2 inches</option>
  <option value="3">3 inches</option>
  <option value="4">4 inches</option>
  <option value="5">5 inches</option>
  <option value="6">6 inches</option>
  <option value="7">7 inches</option>
  <option value="8">8 inches</option>
  <option value="9">9 inches</option>
  <option value="10">10 inches</option>
  <option value="11">11 inches</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<div id="totalinches"></div>
<br>
<h3>Please select your weight:</h3>
<br>

<div id="sliderWeight" class="sliderClass"></div>
<br>
<div id="dynamicweight">Your current weight is <span id="weight"></span> lbs.
</div>
<div id="bmi"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.heavytext {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #29abe2;
}

.sliderClass {
  width: 400px;
}
```

[JSFiddle-BMI Calculator](https://jsfiddle.net/Curlz/s2ss1sro/1/)

Comment: u need to call `displayVals();` in your onslide function i tell ya what

Comment: [peep dis](https://jsfiddle.net/s2ss1sro/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Call display method in slide event

```html
$("#sliderWeight").slider({
    value: 150,
    min: 91,
    max: 443,


    slide: function(evt, elem) {
      $("#weight").text(elem.value);
      displayVals();
    },
    start: function(evt, elem) {
      $("#weight").addClass("heavytext")
    },
    stop: function(evt, elem) {
      $("#weight").removeClass("heavytext")
    }
  });
```